# How to set the aspect ratio of an AVPlayer when attached to a SCNGeometry contents?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, scenekit

I'm creating an `SCNPlane` in SceneKit for video playback. I'm using an `AVPlayer` to play the video from a specified URL. Here's how I do it:

Setting up the plane node:

```
func setupVideoPlaybackPlaneNodes() {
    guard let scene else { return }
    
    let plane = SCNPlane(width: videoPlaybackPlaneWidth, height: videoPlaybackPlaneHeight)
    plane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
    playbackNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    playbackNode?.opacity = videoPlaybackPlaneOpacity

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(playbackNode!)
}
```

Setting up the `AVPlayer` for the node:

```
func setPlayer() {
    let videoURL = /* The local video URL here */
    let videoPlaybackPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    playbackNode?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = videoPlaybackPlayer
}
```

I can't seem to find how to set the aspect ratio of the `AVPlayer` when it's attached to a `SCNGeometry`'s contents. I tried this:

```
videoPlaybackPlayer?.externalPlaybackVideoGravity = .resizeAspect
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: The AVPlayer isn’t something that has a geometry. It doesn’t actually have any visible area you need a video player of some kind.

Comment: @loremipsum then is there any other way to achieve this? I tried using an `AVPlayerLayer` as well but it doesn't show any videos.

Comment: I’m sure there is, I’ve never tried myself. Start your search with how to use a UIView with SCNNode. Once you can present a regular UIView like a UILabel you should be able to put together a UIView with a PreviewLayer like any UIKit sample.